# Drawing arrow only at the start and end of a line string in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, line

I want to draw an arrow only at the end and start of the line string. The arrow should point in the direction of the last / first segment. I have found one way to do this, but it leads to bad performance with large layers. What is the optimal way of achieving this?
Here is the temporary solution I have used to create an arrow at the end of a line string, by taking advantage of the geometry.forEachSegment function.

```
  if (correctStyle.stroke.arrowEnd) {
      const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      // Create an arrow at the end of the line
      const endpoint = geometry.getLastCoordinate();
      geometry.forEachSegment(function (start, end) {
          // Only want to perform these steps if end is equal to endpoint
          if (end[0] !== endpoint[0] || end[1] !== endpoint[1]) {
              return;
          }
          const dx = end[0] - start[0];
          const dy = end[1] - start[1];
          const rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
          currentstyle.push(new Style({
              geometry: new Point(end),
              image: new Icon({
                  src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' +
                      '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">' +
                      '<path d="M 0 0 L 20 10 L 0 20 z" fill="' + correctStyle.stroke.color + '" transform="rotate(' + rotation + ')"></path>' +
                      '</svg>',
                  anchor: [0.75, 0.5],
                  rotateWithView: true,
                  rotation: -rotation
              })
          }));
      });
  }
  currentstyle.push(new Style({
      new Stroke({
      color: jsonstyle.stroke.color,
      width: hover ? jsonstyle.stroke.width * 2 : jsonstyle.stroke.width,
      lineDash: jsonstyle.stroke.lineDash,
      lineCap: jsonstyle.stroke.lineCap ? jsonstyle.stroke.lineCap : undefined
  }));
```

What is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You are creating new style for each arrow. One possible optimization would be to create one static style for arrow and then set its geometry and rotation dynamically when using it. Problem with this approach is that you are also setting icon color, which cannot be done dynamically. Possible solution would be to create as many static icons as there are possible colors for you line strings, but this would require some known limited amount of colors.

Comment: If you only need a filed triangle use a regular shape, then it can be reused with any color `style.getImage().getFill().setColor((color)`